# Enabled php5 on a windows server?

Tags: php, windows, iis

On a Linux server I need to add the following line to .htaccess file.

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .php
```

Is there something similar for a windows server running php4?

Comment: If you are running apache it is exactly the same. IIS has it's own GUI for doing that.

Comment: Its IIS. I have had a look around but cannot find any documentation on translating the above code to IIS. Any idea where I should be looking?

Comment: Not exactly clear what you are trying to accomplish. Off the top of my head I am assuming that you have both PHP4 and 5 on the same server, and want to control whether the files in a certain directory are rendered by the PHP4 or PHP5 engine.  Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

The official reference can be found here:

- http://es2.php.net/manual/en/install.windows.iis.php

You'll notice that the chapter names begin with "Manually installing PHP". If you download the MSI installer version it's normally just a matter of *Next*, *Next*...

(Previously, you'll have to remove PHP 4.)

Comment: The question states that current host has PHP 4. Is it a typo?

Answer (score 0):

I'm think is the same, windows webserver work like other webserver, so try use the same line in a .htaccess into the webserver folder. But i know have some packege u don't need those configuration, u can try intall other webserver like Apache, is better than windows webserver and more faster.

[Apache Friends - Xampp](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html)

Works very well and u have more options to config PHP and other stuffs.